# Why there is no "OR" operator in "...WhereInput" anymore? (prisma 1.25.4)

Tags: prisma

Prisma 1.23 had "OR,AND" in "...WhereInput", but in version 1.25.4 there is no "OR" operator, it's just "AND"

The database is `mongodb`

```
input ProvinceWhereInput {
  AND: [ProvinceWhereInput!]
  id: ID
  id_not: ID
  id_in: [ID!]
  id_not_in: [ID!]
  id_lt: ID
  id_lte: ID
  id_gt: ID
  id_gte: ID
  id_contains: ID
  id_not_contains: ID
  id_starts_with: ID
  id_not_starts_with: ID
  id_ends_with: ID
  id_not_ends_with: ID
  name: String
  name_not: String
  name_in: [String!]
  name_not_in: [String!]
  name_lt: String
  name_lte: String
  name_gt: String
  name_gte: String
  name_contains: String
  name_not_contains: String
  name_starts_with: String
  name_not_starts_with: String
  name_ends_with: String
  name_not_ends_with: String
  cities_some: CityWhereInput
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were disabled to allow for a quicker implementation of relational filters towards non-embedded types (cities_some in your case if it is a non-embedded type would not have been available in 1.23 for example).

You can follow this issue to get notified once they get reenabled. 
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3897